# how do you delete a column's data from a postgresql database using datamapper and sinatra?

Tags: database, postgresql, sinatra, datamapper

I have a table with three columns (id, name, age). I would like to keep the name and id the same, but remove all age data, and be able to reassign ages.

ie. I want to clear data from one column only, but not delete the entire column.

I am using sinatra, datamapper and postgresql.

Comment: In plain SQL: UPDATE table1 SET age = NULL;

Answer (score 2):

Programmatically you could do something like this:

```
@myvariable = MyModel.all
@myvariable.map {|m|
    m.update(:age => nil)
}
```

More info on Datamapper can be found here: http://datamapper.org/docs/

Or if you want to do it by hand, if your database is on Heroku, you can connect to the database instance on Heroku like so:

`heroku pg:psql`

Then you'll be connected to the database and you can just type out the SQL like Gus suggested:

`update table_name set age = NULL`

If your app is not on Heroku and you're just connecting to a local postgresql instance, it would be like so:

`psql -d your_database -U your_user`

More info on psql can be found here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-psql.html